# Do not have placed NBT blocks minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am on a server with a bunch of my friends, and we are playing survival mode.

Blocks with NBT data can be picked up using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + middle mouse button, or obtained using an NBT editor.

However, I would like that items with NBT data are not placeable, even in Survival mode.

Is there a command machine or something of the like that can stop these blocks from being placed?

Comment: i believe you could have a canplaceon tag for some block thats unobtainable, and then have a command setting the player to adventure every time they hold it.

Comment: I thought about it but we have to do a survival. A server I know managed to keep NBT blocks from being placed.

Comment: what do you mean by "NBT blocks" anyway, do you just mean blocks with nbt data (almost every block) or do you mean tile entities, or command blocks?

Comment: NBT tag blocks. When they are placed they lose their tags and then I would like to avoid that they are placed in survival.

Comment: alright, lemme see what i can do

Comment: I updated the post by putting the link of the video where I show what I would like.

Comment: The video link is dead for me.